# jQuery insertAfter only if not inserted before

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this little script that adds a "Read More" button after divs with the class "only-so-big" if the height of the div exceeds a certain amount.

```
var allOSB = [];
var mxh = '';

var setResizeVariables = function() {
  // Set Variables
  allOSB = document.querySelector(".only-so-big :not(.not-these)");

  if (allOSB.length > 0) {
    mxh = window.getComputedStyle(allOSB[0]).getPropertyValue('max-height');
    mxh = parseInt(mxh.replace('px', ''));

    // Add read-more button to each OSB section
    for (var i = 0; i < allOSB.length; i++) {
        var currentOSB = allOSB[i];
      var el = document.createElement("button");
      el.innerHTML = "Read More";
      el.setAttribute("type", "button");
      el.setAttribute("class", "read-more hid");

      insertAfter(allOSB[i], el);
      currentOSB.class += "not-these";
    }
  }

  // Add click function to buttons
  var readMoreButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("read-more");
  for (var i = 0; i < readMoreButtons.length; i++) {
    readMoreButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
      revealThis(this);
    }, false);
  }

  // Update buttons so only the needed ones show
  updateReadMore();
}


// show only the necessary read-more buttons
function updateReadMore() {
  if (allOSB.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allOSB.length; i++) {
      if (allOSB[i].scrollHeight > mxh) {
        if (allOSB[i].hasAttribute("style")) {
          updateHeight(allOSB[i]);
        }
        allOSB[i].nextElementSibling.className = "read-more";
      } else {
        allOSB[i].nextElementSibling.className = "read-more hid";
      }
    }
  }
}

function revealThis(current) {
  var el = current.previousElementSibling;
  if (el.hasAttribute("style")) {
    current.innerHTML = "Read More";
    el.removeAttribute("style");
  } else {
    updateHeight(el);
    current.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
}

function updateHeight(el) {
  el.style.maxHeight = el.scrollHeight + "px";
}


function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

window.onload  = function() {
  setResizeVariables();
}

window.onresize = function() {
  updateReadMore();
}
```

HTML/Blade:

```
<div class="status-body" data-body-status-id="{{ $status->id }}">
    <div class="status-body-text only-so-big">{!! $status->body !!}</div>
</div>
```

However, my current problem is that I'm now calling this function more than once. When this happens, additional "Read more" buttons are added on, leading to multiple buttons. How could it make it so that `insertAfter(allOSB[i], el);` ONLY inserts a new "read more" button if a button with that class doesn't already exist after that div?

Comment: Im quite sure this is not the best option but you could add/remove a class to the element like a flag to know when you should insert a new read more button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a flag to the button to check if you already added the button:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allOSB.length; i++) {
    var currentOSB = allOSB[i];
    if (currentOSB.hasAttribute("data-button-added")) continue; // check if it's been added already
    var el = document.createElement("button");
    el.innerHTML = "Read More";
    el.setAttribute("type", "button");
    el.setAttribute("class", "read-more hid");
    currentOSB.setAttribute("data-button-added", "1"); // add the flag to the current OSB
    insertAfter(allOSB[i], el);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5j1vxxxs/2/

---

This answer was changed extensively. See comments.

Comment: Adding "var currentOSB = allSOB[i];" gives the error "ReferenceError: allSOB is not defined". Edit: wait I see the typo.

Comment: It was a typo. It's supposed to be var currentOSB = allOSB[i];. Already edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. When trying your 2nd response, I get the error "TypeError: allOSB is null"

Comment: I also get the error "TypeError: allOSB is null" when trying your first response.

Comment: On which line? You have a length check so if the selector didn’t work you shouldn’t be able to reach that assignment.

Comment: I tried your code with my modifications (first one) and had no problems... What does insertAfter() look like?

Comment: For the second one, I get the error at " if (allOSB.length > 0) {"

Comment: Edited the main post to show the insertAfter() function.

Comment: In fact, I added all the code that might be relevant. The code is currently what it is at the moment, which gives a "TypeError: allOSB is null" at "if (allOSB.length > 0) {"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152106/discussion-between-felix-maxime-and-ishegg).